# algorithm2e command \procedure already defined

Tags: algorithms, incompatibility, algorithm2e

I included algorithm2e and start getting error message of "algorithm2e.sty command\procedure already defined." Here are the list of packages in my latex file

```
\documentclass[useAMS,usenatbib]{coin.cls}
\def\bSig\mathbf{\Sigma}
\newcommand{\VS}{V\&S}
\newcommand{\tr}{\mbox{tr}}

%\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage[vlined,ruled,linesnumbered, algo2e]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{stfloats}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add a pointer to `coin.cls`?

Answer (score 5):

If you're referring to [`coin.cls`](https://projects.cs.dal.ca/ci/latex/template-files/coin.cls) that forms part of the **Co**mputational **In**telligence group at Dalhousie University's Department of Computer Science, then the solution is fairly straight-forward *if* you want to keep using [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e): set the `\procedure` and `\endprocedure` macros to `\relax`.

[image]

```
% https://projects.cs.dal.ca/ci/latex/template-files/coin.cls
\documentclass{coin}

\let\procedure\relax
\let\endprocedure\relax
\usepackage[algo2e]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm2e}[H]
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm2e}

\end{document}
```

So if you're not going use these theorem-like structures, then there shouldn't be any other conflict.

Both the `algorithm` and `procedure` environments are predefined inside the `coin` document class as theorems:

```
\newtheorem{algorithm}{Algorithm}%[theorem]
%...
\newtheorem{procedure}{Procedure}%[section]
```

The `algorithm` environment definition is avoided by using the `algo2e` option of `algorithm2e`, which creates an `algorithm2e` float rather than `algorithm`.